# Oracle query with different dates

Tags: oracle, select, dense-rank, analytical

I have to write this query, and it is a bit complex.   I am hoping someone can help, as I've received much help from here before.

Say I have a customers stock portfolio.  And a list of company tickers, and the date the ticker was purchased.    My list looks something like this:

```
CYSL  1/16/2017
MCIG  4/1/2016
MSRT  9/13/2016
NTFU  1/16/2017
QNTM  10/30/2014
SIGWX 6/28/2014
TRMCX 6/25/2014
TRT2  4/19/2016
```

Now, in order for my to compute some YTD performance, I need to apply the following logic:

If the purchase date > 01/01/2017, I'll use the closing price of the ticker when it was purchased.
If the purchase date < 01/01/2017. I'll use the closing price of the ticker on <= 12/31/2016.

There are 2 tables involved:  1)  Portfolio Table  2)  Price History

I've gotten this far:

```
SELECT ticker, MIN(transaction_date) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY transaction_date) transaction_date 
FROM customer_portfolios
WHERE portfolio_id = 954118
GROUP BY ticker;
```

This gives me the list above.  Now, I am lost on how to join this with the logic above, to get the proper date, and go after the proper price.

I hope I am explaining this correctly.

And help will be great, and I can explain more if it will help you, help me.

Thank you.

Comment: Landon, would there be anyway you can post a  sample ddl for the price history table? I could forge my own but I don't know how helpful that would be for you.

Comment: Hi Miguel,

The Price History is simple:<BR>
- Price Date<BR>
- Ticker<BR>
- Open Price<BR>
- Closing Price<BR>

Thanks for looking at this.<BR>I'm not sure if it can be done in one query.   (Not sure how to format these comments either)

Comment: I can also do a loop with the above query, but was seeing if I could run a single query to get all the information.

Comment: what is that purchase date, is it that min of trasaction date?

Answer (score 0):

Use `GREATEST` to get the date at either `2016-12-31` or the later transaction date and then just join to the price history table:

```
SELECT cp.ticker,
       cp.transaction_date,
       h.close_price
FROM   (
  SELECT ticker,
         GREATEST(
           DATE '2016-12-31',
           MIN(transaction_date) KEEP (
             DENSE_RANK FIRST
             ORDER BY transaction_date
           )
         ) AS transaction_date 
  FROM customer_portfolios
  WHERE portfolio_id = 954118
  GROUP BY ticker
) cp
INNER JOIN price_history h
ON (   cp.ticker = h.ticker
   AND cp.transaction_date BETWEEN h.start_date AND h.end_date )
```

or if the price history has a row per day (rather than the assumed range in the query above) then replace the last line with:

```
   AND cp.transaction_date = h.price_date )
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, I'm missing something here but without any real sample data, this is the best I can come up with. Below are the table ddl's, inserts and query and an image of the results.

```
  CREATE TABLE PRICE_HISTORY 
   (    PRICE_DATE DATE, 
    TICKER VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    OPEN_PRICE NUMBER, 
    CLOSE_PRICE NUMBER
   )

 CREATE TABLE PORTFOLIO_TABLE 
   (    TICKER VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    TICKER_DATE VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    CUSTOMER VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
   ) 

Insert into PORTFOLIO_TABLE (TICKER,TICKER_DATE,CUSTOMER) values ('CYSL','1/16/2018','1');
Insert into PORTFOLIO_TABLE (TICKER,TICKER_DATE,CUSTOMER) values ('MCIG','04/1/2016','2');
Insert into PORTFOLIO_TABLE (TICKER,TICKER_DATE,CUSTOMER) values ('MSRT','09/13/2016','3');
Insert into PORTFOLIO_TABLE (TICKER,TICKER_DATE,CUSTOMER) values ('NTFU','01/16/2017','4');


Insert into PRICE_HISTORY (PRICE_DATE,TICKER,OPEN_PRICE,CLOSE_PRICE) values (to_date('27-MAR-2017 20:27:12','DD-MON-RRRR HH24:MI:SS'),'CYSL',1,2);
Insert into PRICE_HISTORY (PRICE_DATE,TICKER,OPEN_PRICE,CLOSE_PRICE) values (to_date('16-JUN-1997 20:27:33','DD-MON-RRRR HH24:MI:SS'),'MCIG',1,2);
Insert into PRICE_HISTORY (PRICE_DATE,TICKER,OPEN_PRICE,CLOSE_PRICE) values (to_date('31-MAY-2011 20:27:45','DD-MON-RRRR HH24:MI:SS'),'MSRT',5,8);
Insert into PRICE_HISTORY (PRICE_DATE,TICKER,OPEN_PRICE,CLOSE_PRICE) values (to_date('25-JAN-2021 20:27:55','DD-MON-RRRR HH24:MI:SS'),'NTFU',7,6);


WITH portfolio AS
  ( SELECT TICKER , TICKER_DATE, CUSTOMER FROM PORTFOLIO_TABLE
  )
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN PRICE_DATE > '01-JAN-17'
    THEN CLOSE_PRICE
    ELSE OPEN_PRICE
  END AS AMOUNT,
  PRICE_DATE,
  P.TICKER,
  OPEN_PRICE,
  CLOSE_PRICE
FROM PRICE_HISTORY H,
  PORTFOLIO P
WHERE H.TICKER = P.TICKER;
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The ultimate goal of this query is to get a SUM of the customers portfolio, on his purchases.

This part is working perfectly!

SELECT m_ticker,
         GREATEST(
           DATE '2016-12-31',
           MIN(transaction_date) KEEP (
             DENSE_RANK FIRST
             ORDER BY transaction_date
           )
         ) AS transaction_date 
  FROM customer_portfolio_history
  WHERE portfolio_id = 954118
  GROUP BY m_ticker;

Gives me the data I need:

CYSL    1/16/2017
MCIG    12/31/2016
MSRT    12/31/2016
NTFU    1/16/2017
QNTM    12/31/2016
SIGWX   12/31/2016
TRMCX   12/31/2016
TRT2    12/31/2016

Now it gets trickier.  With the results above, I need to go into the PRICE_HISTORY, and find the price which is on or closest to (earlier) that date.

So, if there is no entry for 12/31/2016 (maybe market was closed), then try 12/30, 12/29, etc.   Same for 1/16/2017.  If there is no entry, then try 1/15, then 1/14....

After, I can take the total # shares from the PORTFOLIO table for that customer / portfolio / ticker, and multiply it by the price I retrieve for the day found.....and there is the value.

Pretty crazy, I know.